# how to deal with ordinal variables for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, ordinal-data

I have a data set that contains an ordinal variable.

The variable is in ranking. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... 30th

I was pre-processing the data set and thinking 'if 1st rank is the best rank (highest rank), I should not give it 1 but the highest number among the 30 rankings?'

So what I did was I gave 1st rank 30, and 2nd rank 29 ... 30th rank 1.

Is my approach fine?

Could someone please explain me how to deal with ordinal data in such case for machine learning?

Comment: Machine Learning is a big generic term. What exactly do you want to do? For most tasks it doesn't matter whether ranks are coded from 1-30 or 30-1, but occasionally it may. Then there are people who'd say that ordinal data should not be simply coded as  numbers, because this suggests that the difference between, e.g., 2 and 3 is the same as 23 and 24, which for ordinal data they don't want to assume. Also to what extent this is a problem depends on what exactly you want to do.